# Failed to read an incomplete http request with NetworkStream

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I have implemented a Server and Client with TcpListener and TcpClient.

Basically the server wait to a client connected to receive data and close, the client will connect, write and close too.

The problem is when I send an incomplete http request the server can't read it. For example "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" is incomplete because it must end with '\r\n' twice, but if i send "PET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" (is not an http request) the server read it fine. What's happened there?

This is my example code:

```
static void Main()
{
    var message = @"GET / HTTP/1.1
";
    var encodingMessage = message.Select(Convert.ToByte).ToArray();

    // SERVER
    var serverThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.48.37"), 23000);
        tcpListener.Start();
        var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        var buffer = new byte[250];
        var bytesCount = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(@"received bytes: {0}", bytesCount);  // print the received bytes
        networkStream.Close();
        networkStream.Dispose();
        tcpClient.Close();
        tcpListener.Stop();
    });
    serverThread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    // CLIENT
    var client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.48.37"), 23000));
    var stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(encodingMessage, 0, encodingMessage.Length);
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();
    client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your code currently reads the first (part of the) data, without any HTTP specific processing. I don't see a reason why it would behave differently for "GET" or "PET".

Comment: The current code dosen't read any data with "GET"

Comment: @C.Evenhuis If you run the code with message "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" it print "received bytes: 0", but with message "PET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" then print "received bytes: 16"

Comment: I added a `Console.ReadKey(true)` at the end of the code to ensure that I would be able to read any output, and used `IPAddress.Loopback` instead of your IP addresses, but otherwise left your sample intact. In both cases (GET and PET) on my box I was receiving 16 bytes as expected, so I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I proved in other pc and work fine, I'm surprised. then what  could be the problem? I test with other ports and I get the same result.